# retrieve an element from a json list with angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs, list

I have this list JSON:

```
[{
    "password" : "ppp",
    "function" : 0,
    "id" : 1,
    "login" : "ness",
    "nom" : "nesrine",
    "mail" : "nes@gmail",
    "tel" : "238555555"
  },
  {
    "password" : "pass",
    "function" : 0,
    "id" : 2,
    "login" : "bilel.troudi",
    "nom" : "bilel",
    "mail" : "bilel.troudi91@gmail",
    "tel" : null
  },
  {
    "password" : "undefined",
    "function" : 1,
    "id" : 4,
    "login" : "undefined",
    "nom" : "ahmed",
    "mail" : "ahmed@gmail.com",
    "tel" : "221474"
  },
  {
    "password" : "khm",
    "function" : 0,
    "id" : 5,
    "login" : "khm",
    "nom" : "khmayes",
    "mail" : "bke@live.fr",
    "tel" : "235684522"
  }
]
```

I want to retrieve the names(nom) of users with angular I recovered this list in a variable in my code.

Comment: The keywords here are `Array` and `Object` in Javascript. Get familiar with these data structures and you will easily achive what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function getNames() {
    return $http.get("/allU").then(function(result) {
        return result.data.map(function(item) {
            return item.nom;
        });
    });
}

getNames().then(function(data) {
    $scope.names = data; //$scope.names = ["nesrine", "bilel", "ahmed", "khmayes"]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.list =[{"password":"ppp","function":0,"id":1,"login":"ness","nom":"nesrine","mail":"nes@gmail","tel":"238555555"},{"password":"pass","function":0,"id":2,"login":"bilel.troudi","nom":"bilel","mail":"bilel.troudi91@gmail","tel":null},{"password":"undefined","function":1,"id":4,"login":"undefined","nom":"ahmed","mail":"ahmed@gmail.com","tel":"221474"},{"password":"khm","function":0,"id":5,"login":"khm","nom":"khmayes","mail":"bke@live.fr","tel":"235684522"}];
$scope.nameList = [];
angular.forEach($scope.list,function(Obj,val){
$scope.nameList.push(Obj.nom);
});
```

you can use this code. in `$scope.nameList` you can get all names.
For this code you have to use angular js

Comment: I defenit in my controller a function that returns json this list : the function is:
 @RequestMapping("/allU")
    public List<Utilisateur> AllU()
    {
     return UtilisateurRepo.findAll();
     
    }

In my code angularjs i use this :
$scope.list =$http
  .get("/allU")
But when i used your code the result was undefined

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use angular js then you can use simple jquery too.

```
var list = [{"password":"ppp","function":0,"id":1,"login":"ness","nom":"nesrine","mail":"nes@gmail","tel":"238555555"},{"password":"pass","function":0,"id":2,"login":"bilel.troudi","nom":"bilel","mail":"bilel.troudi91@gmail","tel":null},{"password":"undefined","function":1,"id":4,"login":"undefined","nom":"ahmed","mail":"ahmed@gmail.com","tel":"221474"},{"password":"khm","function":0,"id":5,"login":"khm","nom":"khmayes","mail":"bke@live.fr","tel":"235684522"}];
var nameList = [];
for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++){
nameList.push(list[i].nom);
}
```